# What is the most memory and cost effective way of reading a file of about 1 Gb in size from Azure Blob storage in .NET Core?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

Need to read the file sequentially. I have been just reading the documentation and did not find any clear guide.

Just wondering in general how much memory is required to download a file of 1 Gb in size from Azure Blob storage.

Answer (score 1):

When downloading a file from Azure Blob Storage or any other storage for that matter, you typically have two main approaches:

###### Stream the file:

This approach reads the file in chunks and writes each chunk to the destination as it's received. This is memory efficient, especially for large files, because it doesn't require loading the entire file into memory. If you're downloading a 1GB file, you don't need 1GB of memory; instead, you just need enough memory for the chunk you're processing.

###### Load the entire file into memory:

This approach is simpler but can be inefficient for large files. If you download a 1GB file this way, you'd generally require around 1GB of memory (a bit more, considering overheads).

With Azure Blob Storage, you'd ideally use streaming, especially for large files.

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

async function downloadBlob(account, sasToken, containerName, blobName, destinationFilePath) {
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

    const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
    const readableStream = downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody;

    if (readableStream) {
        // Write the stream to a file (you could use any writable stream destination)
        readableStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destinationFilePath));
    }
}

const account = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME";
const sasToken = "YOUR_SAS_TOKEN";
const containerName = "YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME";
const blobName = "YOUR_BLOB_NAME";
const destinationFilePath = "path/to/save/file/on/local/disk";

downloadBlob(account, sasToken, containerName, blobName, destinationFilePath);
```

When reading a file from Azure Blob Storage using streaming, especially if you're reading in small chunks, the transaction count can increase significantly. This can indeed affect billing.

###### Blob Storage Transactions:

Azure Blob Storage bills based on the number of transactions. A transaction is any read, write, or delete operation against a blob, container, or any blob service properties or metadata. For instance, every time you make a request to read a chunk of data, it's counted as one transaction.

###### Streaming:

When you download a blob using streaming, and if you specify smaller chunk sizes, each chunk retrieval will count as a transaction. Therefore, downloading a large file in many small chunks will result in many transactions.

For example, if you were to stream a 1GB file in 1MB chunks, you'd end up with 1,000 transactions just from that single download operation.

###### To manage costs effectively:

Adjust Chunk Size:
Larger chunks mean fewer transactions, but they also mean higher memory usage during the download. You'll need to find a balance that's appropriate for your application and infrastructure.

Comment: can you please share a code example? 
I also read that if you use streaming while reading a file from azure blob storage, transaction count increases significantly which affects billing?

Comment: @NabeelRiaz updated answer above.

Comment: Daredevil, really sorry if I am bothering you. You have cleared some concepts, but I just want to ask some more questions. The code snippet you provided, it seems to be loading the entire file into memory, right? can you please provide an example of streaming as well. It would be great if the example is in .net core, but node is also ok if the code is well commented.  My .net core app will be deployed on Azure App Service with B1 service plan. Please share some specific optimization if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Upvote.  @nabeel you've gotten good advice here.  please do not ask the person to "do the entire thing" for you.  it is bad SOF etiquette.  what have YOU tried?

Comment: @granadaCoder My apologies for any confusion. What I intended to convey was that I would appreciate some clarification regarding whether I should use DownloadToAsync or OpenReadAsync from the example provided on the Microsoft Azure documentation page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-download). I'm seeking guidance on which option is the most cost and memory-efficient. I believe it would be helpful to include both examples in the answer: one for streaming and one for downloading the file, to provide clarity for both current and future readers.

Comment: This is my first time asking a question, and I want to extend my apologies to @Daredevil if my inquiry seems excessive. I can't upvote as of now. I don't have the reputation.